# Rotate map with dynamic display layer?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects

I am developing an application using the dynamic layer.

However, I have trouble rotating the map (Not the same as rotating data frame by default).

See more details: https://geonet.esri.com/videos/1617

This is an example of the directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.1\Samples\ArcObjectsNet\MyDynamicDisplayApp\CSharp
```

Link to download this example:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0_zDbofmbfZOVFlSDhkQXVWM3c
```

Comment: Please help me !

Comment: Google docs link is dead.